# Dynamic variables and function calls in XML files

Tags: c++, xml, xml-parsing, interpreter

I'm using libxml2 to parse xml documents for my application. I want the ability to use variables and even function calls in the XML. For example, something like:

< Element attr1="$variable1" attr2="=rand(1, 2, 3, 4)" />

The variables may be defined in the XML and reused, or defined/hardcoded somewhere in the code loading the XML.  The functions may be defined in the code (i.e. calling C functions from the XML).

My application already loads XML documents and I can load and modify the XML in memory, but I would like to know: what is the best way to evaluate the variables and function calls?

Are there any XML libraries or interpreter libraries that I can use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to implement a simple parser (or complex, depending on what you need), which can understand variables and functions.

First step is to extract the expressions from  `attr1="$variable1"` - in the simple case, that's just a matter of looking at the first character inside the string to see if it's a `'$'` or `'='`.

If all variables are integers, you can easily store variables in a `std::map<std::string, int>`. If the value is allowed to be multiple types, then you can either store the value as a string (and convert as needed), or have a struct/class that includes information about what the actual content type is.

Evaluating expressions like `=rand(1,2,3,4)` would involve some sort of "string to function" construct. A very simple way is an if/else chain. Here we assume that you have extracted the function name as a standalone string called `funcname`

```
if (funcname == "rand") 
{
    ... do stuff here... 
} 
else if (funcname == "sin")
{
    .... 
}
```

A more complex, but often more effective solution is to have a structure that contains a string and a function pointer. Search for the string, and call the function.

Another alternative is to use `std::map<std::string, functionType>` where `functionType` is a typedef of a standardized function.

Bot of the latter two solutions pretty much relies on having a standard function type. You can standardise the function by for example having a `std::vector<Arg> args` as the arguments - the functions can check the number of arguments with `if (args.size() != 4) print_error("wrong number of arguments");`.

I hope this helps you along the way...

Comment: Thanks, for the answer. I have started the way you suggested. Also generating some syntax graphs to support more complex combinations of text, variables and functions. I edited my question -- would really like a library, interpreter, etc. that does all this for me.